# Confusing variance question

Tags: probability, variance, distributions

> $E(x) = 4$ and $V(x) = 6$
>
> What is the variance of $y=5x+2$?

$E(5x+2) = 5\times 4+2 = 22$

I don't get how the answer is 150

I thought it was $(x-\bar{x})^2$

$(4-22)^2 =324$

very confused

Comment: The original question was presumably  "What is the variance of y=5x+2 e(5x+2) ?", and the following "= 5*4+2 = 22" is your working - could you please edit your question to clarify?

Comment: Edited sorry didn't do a double space

Comment: Thanks. Have you ever come across the difference between the variance of a sample & the variance of a random variable, & have you studied the properties of variance & expectation? If not you might be better off reading up on them, in e.g. [Grinstead & Snell (2006), *Introduction to Probability", Ch.6](https://math.dartmouth.edu/~prob/prob/prob.pdf), as there'd be a awful lot to cover for a Cross Validated answer. A terse account of the properties of variance you need for this question is given in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Basic_properties).

Comment: $\operatorname{var}(aX+b) = a^2\cdot\operatorname{var}(X)$

Comment: Thanks Dilip. Can I ask how you figured this out?

Comment: @Ivan: It's a standard result. I've given a derivation, but this isn't a topic you're going to grasp through trying to answer questions in a piecemeal fashion; I reiterate my advice to study a textbook.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Basic_properties

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\newcommand{\Var}{\mathrm{Var}}
\newcommand{\E}{\mathrm{E}}
\begin{array}{r l l}
\Var[cX+b]
&= \E [(cX+b - \E[cX+b])^2] & \text{definition of variance}\\
&= \E [(cX+b - c \E[X+b/c])^2] & \text{take $c$ outside expection}\\
&= \E[c^2(X + b/c -  \E[X+b/c])^2] & \text{take $c$ outside square}\\
&= c^2 \E[(X + b/c -  \E[X+b/c])^2] & \text{take $c^2$ outside expection}\\
&= c^2 \E[(X + b/c - \E[X] - \E[b/c])^2] & \text{separate terms in expection}\\
&= c^2 \E[(X + b/c - \E[X] - b/c)^2] & \text{expection of constant}\\
&= c^2 \E[(X - \E[X])^2]  & \text{$b/c$ terms cancel}\\
&= c^2 \Var[X] \\
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Or, more simply, $$\newcommand{\Var}{\mathrm{Var}}\begin{align}\Var(cX+b)&=E [(cX+b - E[cX+b])^2]\\&= E[(cX+b-E[cX]-b)^2]\\&=E[(cX-E[cX])^2]\\&=\Var(cX)\\&=E[(cX-cE[X])^2]\\&=c^2E[(X-E[X])^2]\\&=c^2\Var(X)\end{align}$$Mathematical derivation aside, Ithink of the result as follows. The variance is the moment of inertia of the probability mass about the center of mass, and so $b$ is irrelevant: the center of mass moves by $b$ rightwards when all the masses move. On the other hand, the $c$ _spreads_ the masses apart by a factor of $c$ and so the moment of inertia increases by a factor of $c^2$.

Comment: @DilipSarwate: Yes, much neater.

Comment: @DilipSarwate: Would you make this an answer?

Comment: The relationship is obvious and immediate once you recognize that (a) the variance, being a measure of dispersion about the center, is invariant under shifts of location; (b) units of measurement of a variance are in terms of the squares of the units of measurement of $X$; and (c) $cX+b$ represents a rescaling of the units by a factor $c$. The first shows that the $+b$ has no effect while the second and third show that the original variance will just be rescaled by $c^2$.